# Compare part of filenames in two directories

Tags: linux, images, bash-scripting

I have two directories say Directory1 and Directory2. They both contain images with some numbers and string. Directory1 contains the blurred Images with number and _blur string like, 001_blur.png. It contains about 62k images. Directory2 contains corresponding fine images say 001_fine.png. It contains 60k images.

The problem is that I lost some blur images from Directory1 that have corresponding fine pair in Directory2. And I lost some fine images in Directory2 that has corresponding blur image in Directory1.

Now i would like to save just the images that have corresponding pair. I mean if one of the corresponding image is not present, I would like to delete them, and just put the images with pairs.

So my Directory format is:

```
Directory1
    001_blur.png
    002_blur.png
    003_blur.png
    004_blur.png

Directory2
    001_fine.png
    002_fine.png
    003_fine.png
    005_fine.png
```

Note: I would like to keep 001 pair, 002 pair, and 003 pair. I would like to copy the blur to Directory3 and fine to Directory4.

I think this problem also has some algorithmic complexity as the images are about 60k in each folder. If I take one image from Directory1 and try to search for corresponding fine image in Directory2, I think the complexity is high. So how do I deal with this algorithmic complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[allo's approach](https://superuser.com/a/1226358/432690) to read directories content once, parse text data and delete files at the end seems good. However that answer seems not to acknowledge the difference between filenames in the two directories (`blur` vs. `fine`).

Your files are named according to patterns, therefore their names shouldn't include nasty surprises like unprintable characters, newlines or so. Parsing `ls` should be safe but in general [one shouldn't do it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). I'd like to give a general solution so I won't parse `ls` here. I will use null-terminated strings, hence the switches like `-print0` and `-z` all over.

Let's start. You only need to adjust the paths in variable declarations, unless you copy to another filesystem(s). If so, you should also adjust `cp -l`. **Read comments first.** I advise you to paste the whole codeblock to a file, adjust, then source or execute it.

```
#/bin/bash

# Declare variables.
dir1="/your/directory1/"
dir2="/your/directory2/"
dir3="/your/new/directory3/" # Use absolute paths at least for dir3...
dir4="/your/new/directory4/" # and dir4.
core1=blur
core2=fine

# Create temporary file.
tmpf=$(mktemp)

# Get null-terminated local paths from dir1.
# Note the line doesn't end yet thanks to \.
{ (cd "$dir1"; find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*${core1}*" -print0) ; \

# Add null-terminated local paths from dir2
# (the line continues because of the trailing |)
(cd "$dir2"; find -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*${core2}*" -print0) |

# but convert core2 to core1, so the names are all with core1.
# Note the output of the two finds is gathered by {} and piped...
sed -z "s|${core2}|${core1}|" ; } |

# ...to sort and uniq. With uinq -d we print only duplicates, only once.
sort -z | uniq -zd > "$tmpf"

# Note how long this one line was.

# At this moment tmpf lists all the files we need to copy to dir3.
# The filenames are local to dir1, so we have to cd temporarily.
# dir3 will be resolved from dir1, that's why I told to use absolute paths.
# I assume the same filesystem. Creating hardlinks instead of copying;
# remove -l option to do regular copy. Hardlinking.
(cd "$dir1"; xargs -0 -a "$tmpf" cp -alt "$dir3")

# Convert core1 to core2 in tmpf in place.
sed -zi "s|${core1}|${core2}|" "$tmpf"

# Hardlinking from dir2 to dir4.
(cd "$dir2"; xargs -0 -a "$tmpf" cp -alt "$dir4")

# Remove the temporary file.
rm "$tmpf"
```

Comment: I think dir1 should be "$dir1" and same for dir2. But after I make these changes and run it, it says cp:missing file operand. I think we should use -exec cp {}, something like this. I am not sure.

Comment: @Dharma Thank you. It's a lesson for me: never use the same directory names and their variables in your test environment, or else such bugs will slip through. I cannot identify the `cp` issue for now. Can you tell me what  your OS is?

Comment: I am working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: @Dharma OK, `missing file operand` is returned if `$tmpf` is empty, i.e. if every `find` found nothing. When you debugged on your own, are you sure you quoted `$dir1` and `$dir2`? Or maybe `core1` and `core2` are set wrong? (e.g. you used "blur" and "fine" in the question but actually your files are described in some other language).

Comment: Great It works. sorry my mistak, I had a typo on fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following loop to put everything in Directory3, and then delete Directory1 and Directory2:

```
mkdir Directory3
cd Directory1
for file in *
do
    # note that the second "cp" is only executed if the first one succeeds:
    cp ../Directory2/${file/blur/fine} ../Directory3/ 2>/dev/null && cp $file ../Directory3/
done
cd ..
#rm -rf Directory1 Directory2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two sorted dirlistings and compare them.

```
# create the listings
cd Directory1;ls|sed 's/_blur\.png//' >../list1.txt;cd ..
cd Directory2;ls|sed 's/_fine\.png//' >../list2.txt;cd ..
# sort the items, then deduplicate them (uniq) and add the count (-c)
cat list1.txt list2.txt|sort|uniq -c >counts.txt
```

This should give you a list of filenames preceded with 1 or 2.
Then you can do

```
# for each line which starts with a 1, remove the 1 and use it as filename
for file in $(grep '^1' counts.txt|sed 's/^1 //');do
    # delete it from first or second directory
    test -f "Directory1/${file}_blur.png" && echo rm "Directory1/${file}_blur.png"
    test -f "Directory2/${file}_fine.png" && echo rm "Directory2/${file}_fine.png"
done
```

If it works, remove the echo. But please test it before.

Comment: How does your solution handle the fact the filenames are different (`blur` vs. `fine`)? I don't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I did not handle it. I updated the answer by removing the suffix with ``sed`` from the dirlistings and adding it for the delete commands. But the script starts to get too complicated for quick & dirty shell pipes, i would consider solving it another way (i.e. with a short python script using the ``glob`` and ``shutils`` modules).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `_blur` image with no corresponding `_fine|:

```
for f in Dir1/*blur.png;do [[ -f Dir2/$(basename $f _blur.png)_fine.png ]] || echo rm $f;done
```

Try once as above, then, if it seems to be doing the Right Thing, remove `echo` to actually remove the files.

The command to remove the `_fine` that have no corresponding `_blur` is left as an exercise to the reader.